# How to resolve Invalid Query selector when dynamically generating ID in .net

Tags: javascript, razor

I am trying to access an element using id.

The catch is as follows:

- I am generating the id using razor Syntax.
- I am then passing the string as parameters to a function.
- In that function I am using document.Query("#id") selector.

My function:

```
 function upload(x , y, z  ) {

            var selector = "\"" + "#" + z + x + "\"";
            console.log(selector);
            var form = document.querySelector(selector);
                var formData = new FormData(form);
 ...}

 The console.log() is correct.
```

> It shows "#a1.3"

which is the id of the dynamically generated HTML element. Just to be sure,I removed special characters from id and gave just characters.

But I still get the same error.

I have no clue why it might be happening.

Comment: Is the id `"#a1.3"` a valid id? maybe you meant to say `#a1.3` without the double quotes. `var selector = "#" + z + x;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the period in that selector...

```
"#a1\\.3"
```